# How to specify screen transition as slide-horizontal

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react native navigation v2. In v1 of the library  screen transition was specified as animationType : 'slide-horizontal'.
How to specify the screen transition in V2 of the library.

Answer (score 0):

According to V2 [documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/styling?id=options-object-format)

> animationType: 'parallax', // defaults to none if not provided,
>   options are 'parallax', 'door', 'slide', or 'slide-and-scale'

Try "slide" option

Comment: This is for the side menu. I want to change the transition for screen push

Comment: any luck for solution?